# How to create stored procedure with Magento 2.3.x setup script.?

Tags: database, magento2.3.4

I'm trying to create MySQL stored procedure using Magento 2.3.x for one of my requirements.

I found that that there is no way in Magento 2.3 declarative schema by which I can create that.

But if the stored procedure is created in the MySQL I'm able to call that using Magento.

Please let me know if there any specific way to create a stored procedure using Magento 2.3 declarative schema.

Comment: You found a way?

Comment: yes, you can do it via installSchema

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking into this, the best I could find was the method explained in this answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321531/93665